# How to call to a given extension number from any phones(landline or basic set) in Elastix 5.0 3CX phone system

Tags: ivr, 3cx

I have installed Elastix 5.0(3CX Phone system) in vmware workstation to setup IVR. I have created extensions 112,113,335 in 'Extensions' and in 'Digital Receptionist' I have created an extension 800, recorded a voice saying press 1 for so and so, press 2 for so and so,assigned menu key 1 and 2 to extension 112 and 335 respectively. I can able to call to 800 extension from 'Zoiper5' or from my android smart phone using 3CX android application. Everything works fine from Zoiper and 3CX app. But I want to implement this from normal phones, like user should call from any phone(basic set or android phone or iphone or landline) to given extension number so that after receiving they should hear prompt(audio). User should not depend on any application to call to a given number.

- User should able to call from any phones(landline, smart phones, basic phone).
- If user gives miss call to a given extension number, I should be able to call back to them.

How to setup this in Elastix 5.0 3CX phone system? Please help me out.

Comment: Not to extension number, how to give miss call to Main number from normal phones without soft phones?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like You have telephony system without SIP trunk or another telco connection - all this extensions in internal, you need SIP trunk to connect from external.

When You add SIP trunk (with DID number) You just need to setup "Route calls to" extension 800.

For example on http://actio.pl You can easly registered account with 1 polish DID number which is actually SIP trunk account.

Comment: You need to configure 2 parts:
SIP Trunks - to connect your 3cx with some external numer
Digital Receptionist - another tye of extension which should work better then yours 800. Read about this two features and I think You will know how to do this setup